# How to initialize FuelUX checkbox with knockout binding

Tags: jquery, checkbox, knockout.js, fuelux

I am using KnockoutJS for my client-side viewmodel needs, and I'm using FuelUX for some styling of my components.

I have several checkboxes on a form whose value is bound to a knockout observable, but when the checkbox binding is checked on page load, FuelUX does not display the checkbox as being checked unless I mouse over the checkbox.  Once I mouse over the checkbox it displays the correct state.

The knockout binding occurs in a ready function, so the page is already loaded when the checked state is applied, so I think that might be the issue.  For some reason FuelUX is not picking up this change.

Is there a way to force FuelUX to refresh the state of checkboxes?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have the same issue here.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I was searching for something else and came across it so I thought I would provide a solution. The check mark is part of the label element in Fuel UX. So you can do it like this:

```
<label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox" data-bind="css: { checked: paid }">
    <input id="Paid" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: paid">
    <span class="checkbox-label">Paid</span>
</label>
```

Notice the `data-bind` on the label? This applies the CSS class `'checked'` when the check box is checked. This is the same class that is applied by Fuel UX.

Comment: I just updated FuelUX to the newest version (3.15.12) and had the same problem. This solution fixed it!

Comment: If building the html without using a binding, just apply 'checked' to the label's classname when you want the initial state to be checked, and then the fuelux will take over once the mouseover occurs.